# How Can I Pull In A Specific Posts Custom Field?

Tags: wordpress, cookies, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I’m using the plugin Last Viewed Posts version 0.72 in conjunction with Wordpress to develop a feature on our Apartment Explorer page. Basically the plugin pulls in the title and image of previously viewed apartments or simply past posts viewed. The title and image are pulled in fine however I need to also pull in a custom field attached to these apartment posts.

This is the code I place inside the plugin file:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="beds"]'); ?>
```

This does load the custom field data however the data being displayed is incorrect. The bedroom number is either 1 or 2 across all recently visited apartments, seemingly the number is being pulled from somewhere different than the actual post bedroom custom field.

HOW TO SEE ISSUE:

See [here](https://portraittwo.co.uk/apartment-picker/)

If you click an apartment and then click another, a “recently viewed apartments” feature will appear at the bottom of the page, this is where the aforementioned plugin comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Passing The post Id in place of 123

```
print_r(get_fields(123));
```

For Further Reference Follow

> https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/

Comment: Thanks, the issue is the same however. I believe the issue is coming from how you enter the Apartment Picker clickthrough itself, they're two options; One Bedroom Apartments and two.